Passing a React ref to deeply nested child components
I need to controle a ref (React useRef) from the parent component. The ref is in a deeply nested child component.
Do I have to use forwardRef in every child component, till I reach the HTML element where the ref is defined?

You can use a context to directly pass your ref.
You already have a detailed explanation in this question. => How do I pass ref to a neighbour component
